# Добавление и сохранение новых данных в массиве

Tags: c#

Я должен создать меню с модулями:

1. Директор. Позволяет добавлять учителей, и удалять их.
2. Информер. Выдает информацию об имеющихся в школе учителях.

Всё это в бесконечном цикле.

К коду: у меня есть изначальный массив учителей teachersForDirector, состоящий из 10 учителей.
Если пользователь захочет добавить учителя или удалить его, то я использую методы DeletingTeachers, AddingTeachers.
Проблема в том, что когда я выбираю модуль "информер", значения массива teachersForDirector сбрасывается к изначальному.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы измененные данные сохранялись и модуль информер выдавал корректную информацию?

Код:

```
        public static List<string> DeletingTeachers(List<string> arrayTeachers)
        {
            int counter = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("какого учителя хотели бы удалить? [индекс]");

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayTeachers.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"учитель под номером - {counter} {arrayTeachers[i]}");
                counter++;
            }
            int index = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            arrayTeachers.RemoveAt(index);
            Console.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayTeachers.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"новый набор учителей - {arrayTeachers[i]}");
            }
            return arrayTeachers;
        }
        public static List<string> AddingTeachers(List<string> arrayTeachers)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("введи имя нового учителя");
            arrayTeachers.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            // Resize(ref teachers, 5);
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayTeachers.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{arrayTeachers[i]}");
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("данные об учителях:"); 
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayTeachers.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{arrayTeachers[i]}");
            }
            return arrayTeachers;
        }
   
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                List<string> teachersForDirector = new List<string> { "Матвеева Н.В", "Ивашина А.С", "Изюмов Р.Н.", "Жиделев А.С.", "Карпов М.Д", "Петрова О.А", "Таран Г.Г.", "Овчарова Д.Е.", "Андреев Д.Е.", "Долгих Н.О." };

                Console.WriteLine("выберите кто вы:\nдиректор - 0 \nинформер - 1"); // MAIN MENU                
                int DirectorZeroInformerOne = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Clear();
                if (DirectorZeroInformerOne == 0) // ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ УЧИТЕЛЕЙ
                {
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("вы хотите удалить учителя[1] или добавить нового[2]?");
                        int chooseDeleteOrNew = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Clear();
                        if (chooseDeleteOrNew == 1) // УДАЛЕНИЕ УЧИТЕЛЯ
                        {
                            DeletingTeachers(teachersForDirector);
                        }
                        if (chooseDeleteOrNew == 2) // ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ УЧИТЕЛЯ
                        {
                            AddingTeachers(teachersForDirector);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (DirectorZeroInformerOne == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Информация об учителях");
                    for (int i = 0; i < teachersForDirector.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(teachersForDirector[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: что такое `модуль "информер"`?

Comment: @tym32167 выдает информацию об имеющихся учителях.

Comment: Вот эту строчку `List<string> teachersForDirector = …` на три строки вверх уберите за цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

teachersForDirector переменная должна быть инициализирована только один раз вне цикла while:

```
        List<string> teachersForDirector = new List<string> ...
        while (true)
        {
```